# In fallout 3 where can I find the power armor training perk

Tags: fallout-3

I am right after finding the fat man and I found power armor it ts repaired but I need to find a perk to wear it help me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This perk is acquired from Brotherhood of Steel:

> After gaining permission from Elder Lyons, speak to Paladin Gunny in
>   the Bailey (Courtyard) of the Citadel. There is no charge or other
>   requirement for training - the screen simply fades to black as Gunny
>   begins teaching it. Once that's done, the Lone Wanderer may use any
>   kind of power armor, including the Enclave and the Outcast variants.
>
> If having not asked for training on one's own, it will automatically
>   be given at the end of The American Dream when becoming an honorary
>   member of Lyons' Pride, however, these options appear very late in the
>   main quest. ([Wiki-Link](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Power_Armor_Training))

Answer (score 0):

additionally, Operation: Anchorage and don't mind a little work, you automatically receive the Power Armor Training perk and an unbreakable suit of T-51b power armor when you open the Armory.